# Array of Arrays with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show a list grouped by date but the list isn't sorted and I don't know when the date change.
It's like I have this Json :

```
list = 
{name: first, date: 2014-05-21}, {
{name: second, date: 2014-05-20}, {
{name: third, date: 2014-05-21}
```

I'd like to make the following html :

```
<li><h3>2014-05-21</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>third</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><h3>2014-05-20</h3>
 <ul>
 <li>second</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Do you have an idea ?

I tried to make an Array of arrays with two ng-repeat like this :

```
for (i in list){
 if ($scope.listToShow[list.date] == undefined) {
     $scope.listToShow[list.date] = newArray();
 }
 $scope.listToShow[list.date].push(list[i]); 
}
```

But I don't success to show this.

Comment: I d rearrange the `list` array so that date fields are unique and `name` is an array. then all you need is two ng-repeats, first is for the `list` array such as `(key, value)` and second is for the `value.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-grouping-nested-ngrepeat-lists-in-angularjs.htm), it exactly mention what you want to achieve.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-grouping-nested-ngrepeat-lists-in-angularjs.htm 
**OR**

You can also use `ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end` (inbuilt directives) to achieve the same.
[Click here](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/displaying-groups-with-angularjs-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-with-example) for Reference link.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved a working example. Is not very sophisticated and could be improved, but you get the basic idea by looking at the code. The trick is to group your data (no fancy angular feature, just plain old javascript) and then display the grouped data in the view. I had to mantain a `keys` property for the `grouped` object because apparently angularjs views dont' support `Object.keys(obj)`.

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/kVMx7/2/)

EDIT: updated with the `(key,obj) in grouped` construct, no more need for `keys` array.

Answer (score 1):

I was [testing](http://jsfiddle.net/henkieee/Lt7aP/1348/) a bit with a array of arrays inside a table. It's not the cleanest one.

```
//controller
$scope.list = [
    [
        {name: 'first', date: '2014-05-21'},
        {name: 'lala', date: '2014-07-32'},
        {name: 'fada', date: '2014-07-32'}
    ], 
    [
        {name: 'second', date: '2014-05-20'},
        {name: 'dada', date: '2014-54-32'},
        {name: 'mama', date: '2014-07-32'}
    ], 
    [
        {name: 'third', date: '2014-05-21'},
        {name: 'nana', date: '2014-78-32'},
        {name: 'rara', date: '2014-07-32'}
    ]
];

//view
<table>
    <tr class="parent" ng-repeat-start="(key, item) in list">
        <td>{{ item[0].name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item[0].date }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child" ng-repeat-end="", ng-repeat="part in list[key].slice(1, list[key].length)">
        <td>{{ part.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ part.date }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```