# how to create Array of Arrays in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I need a array of arrays and I can't get it and I cant understand what am I doing wrong..this is my code..

```
c.push({ id: data[0]["id"], title:data[v]["title"], date:data[v]["date"],
         text:data[v]["text"], favorit:"true" });
$scope.favoriti.push({c});
c=[];
```

I'm trying to access the array with this, but it write undefined

```
alert( $scope.favoriti[0]["id"] );
```

What I must write, to get that kind of a array where can I access with that alert. I really need help, I try everything. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of Arrays with ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801879/array-of-arrays-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: Remove curly brackets at $scope.favoriti.push(c);

Comment: i need that kind a array for ng-repeat.
  removing {} does'nt help :/

Comment: makes no sense pushing something into `c` then overwriting the whole `c` variable immediately after. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Why? I create a array(c) i that array i want to push in another array?

Comment: .`c.push(something); c=[] ;` ... is now an empty array. You need to provide a [mcve] if you want more help. A plunker demo would really help

Comment: You have two arrays and an object (`$scope.favoriti` is an array containing `c` which is an array containing the object literal). So you need one more index to address the content of `$scope.favoriti`

Comment: ... and ... of course ... you NEED to remove the `{}` around `c` when pushing it

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
  var c = [];
  $scope.favoriti = [];
  var v = 0;
  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 't',
    date: 'd',
    text: 'text'
  }]
  c.push({
    id: data[0]["id"],
    title: data[v]["title"],
    date: data[v]["date"],
    text: data[v]["text"],
    favorit: "true"
  });
  $scope.favoriti.push(c);
  console.log($scope.favoriti);
  console.log("id : " + $scope.favoriti[0][0]["id"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
</div>
```